# Perl: Nested Hash

Tags: perl, hash

I'm trying to write a script to produce a nested hash. My first key/value pair consists of two identifiers - each type of main identifier in the 4th column has a corresponding identifier in 3rd column (can be of variable length), and an associated numeric value in the 6th column.

I was thinking of constructing a key value pair for the identifiers and then sorting the keys (A, B, C, etc.) before incorporating the numerical identifier in a second hash.

**Input File**

```
CATE      1  CA   A     1       108.8
CATE      2  CB   A     1       8.33
CATE      3  CA   B     1       45.1
CATE      4  CB   B     1       3.96
CATE      5  CG   B     1       3.94
CATE      6  CA   C     1       1.96
CATE      7  CB   C     1       2.94
```

Below is my script - when I run it, I don't get any output, and I'm uncertain as to why.

**Input Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $key;
my $value;
my %hash;
my @fields;

my $filename = 'data.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Can't open $filename:$!";

while(my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    @fields = split /\s+/, $line;
    $key = $fields[3];
    $value = $fields[2];
    $hash{$key} = $value;
}

foreach my $name (sort keys %hash) {
    foreach my $type (keys %{ $hash{$fields[5]}}) {
        print "$name, $type: $hash{$name}{$type}\n";
    }
}
```

**Expected Hash structure**

```
A     CA     108.8
      CB     8.33
B     CA     45.1
      CB     3.96
      CG     3.94
C     CA     1.96
      CB     2.94
```

Comment: It's not quite clear to me. Do you want a hash with `{'CA'}{'A'} = 108.8` and `{'CB'}{'A'} = 8.33` etc.?

Comment: @PerlDuck yes, that's exactly right

Comment: Well, it's not exactly what I guessed, but thanks to your edit we now know what you want. Thank you for editing.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by *corresponding* and *associated*. Which column, exactly, "can be of variable length"? Why is the column containing `CATE` not column 1?

Comment: @Borodin … because counting starts at 0? There are 6 columns, so I presume they are numbered 0..5.

Comment: Hashes are unsorted. Do you need any specific sorted output?

Comment: Tip: Don't declare all the variables at the start. Limit the scope of variables to where they are used. For example, `@fields` only makes sense within the `while` loop, so its scope should be limited to the `while` loop, and you would have instantly noticed you were doing something wrong when you tried to use it outside of the `while` loop.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks, noted.

Comment: @PerlDuck: Counting *never* starts at zero. Cardinal numbers start at one. Ordinal numbers can start anywhere, and are only relevant in a context where that start is defined or implicit, such as array indices. "Column 1" isn't an array index.

Comment: @Borodin You are right, the problem description is not "machine readable" in this regard. I just made an educated guess to know which column is which based on my experience with array indices, column counting, and the code given. I'm afraid it worked.

Comment: @PerlDuck: We *still* don't know whether it's the hash that they want or the output. It doesn't look like a very useful hash structure unless you already know what's in there.

Comment: @Borodin, I wanted the hash structure. I'll be using this data file as a lookup table.

Comment: @EA00: The thing is, as I said, it doesn't look very useful for anything as you have to either know already what's in the hash or you need to search it. Hashes are meant for a very quick lookup when you know the key, and if you're searching through them then you are better off with a simple array of records. Like `my @data = map [ split ], <>`

Comment: @Borodin thanks for the suggestion - I'll look into map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', \<<EOF;
CATE      1  CA   A     1       108.8
CATE      2  CB   A     1       8.33
CATE      3  CA   B     1       45.1
CATE      4  CB   B     1       3.96
CATE      5  CG   B     1       3.94
CATE      6  CA   C     1       1.96
CATE      7  CB   C     1       2.94
EOF

my %data;

while (<$fh>) {
    my ($key1, $key2, $val) = (split)[3,2, 5];
    $data{$key1}{$key2} = $val;
}

#use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%data;

for my $name (sort keys %data) {
    my $href = $data{$name};
    for my $type (sort keys %$href) {
        print "$name, $type, $href->{$type}\n"; 
    }   
}
```

Output

```
A, CA, 108.8
A, CB, 8.33
B, CA, 45.1
B, CB, 3.96
B, CG, 3.94
C, CA, 1.96
C, CB, 2.94
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        #!/usr/bin/perl -w
        use strict;
        use warnings;
        use Data::Dumper;
        open(DATA, "<test.txt") ;
        open(DATA1, ">>test.txt") ;

        while(<DATA>){
            my $data=$_;
            $data=~s/\s+/ /ig;
           my @arr= split(' ',$data);
           my $data1 .= "$arr[3]  $arr[2] $arr[5] \n";
           #print STDERR Dumper($data1);
           print DATA1 $data1;
        }
        close(DATA);
        close(DATA1);
```